# asp.net string with different format to datetime when save to database

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to save the string value of textbox to database as `datetime` and for updating/edit I want to display it again in textbox as string. This is due to the datetime that will be inputted will be copied from outlook and be pasted in textbox to be use easily by the user. I have no idea how to do it. Please help me with this. Thank you

Sample string: `Thu 1/27/2022 8:37 AM`

**.cshtml part**

```
<input id="txtDateTime" maxlenght="25" type="text" class="form-control" />
......
```

**.js part (saving call cs)**

```
SaveData: function(){
   var datetime = $("#txtDateTime").val();
   
   if(datetime == null || datetime == ""){
      alert("Datetime is required");
      return;
   }
   
   $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "POST",
      datatype: "JSON"
      data: {
         ......,
         DateTime: datetime
      }
   }).done(function(data)){
     ...........,
   }
}
```

**.cs part (saving to db)**

```
public int AddData(Model data, out string outMessage)
{
   using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnect(Common.DBConnection))
   {
     cn.Open();
     using (SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
     {
       cmd.CommandText = "sp_add_data";
       cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTime", data.DateTime);
       .......,

       SqlParameter paramStatus = new SqlParameter();
       .......,

       SqlParameter paramMessage = new SqlParameter();
       .......,

       outMessage = paramMessage.Value.ToString();
       return Convert.ToInt32(paramStatus.Value.ToString());
     }
   }
}
```

**sp_add_data**

```
@DateTime datetime,
.....,
//insert script
```

Hope you can help me with this thank you.

Comment: First, I suggest you define a date format (like `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`) when the user types the date in the textbox. It would be better if you can rebuild the same date in order to parse it easily sever side. Once sent to the server, you parse or convert the date as a`DateTime` that you can store in your database. If timezone management is required in your app, then store it as **ISO-8601** UTC datetime (e.g: `2022-02-09T23:35:19Z`). The converted datetime you'll get should be selectable/insertable/updatable in your database.

Comment: If you want to show back exactly what the user has inputted it will be hardly possible. Even if you can store date format in the database, you can't force users to input date formats there. Maybe it is possible to parse this date on JS side with the current user date format and pass it to BE in one date format.

Comment: @RivoR. but the user told me that they just want to copy paste it from the outlook's timestamp. That's why I have not declared/defined the format. That's the format they want to input to textbox.

Comment: @Serhii - The user's system or browser default datetime format can take over. So theoretically you will end up with the same initial format again client-side.

Comment: @Rymrk - ok so you will have to parse the date via JS to rebuild (using `get_day()`, `get_month()`, `get_FullYear()` etc.) and format it so that the server will be able to parse it via C#.

Comment: @RivoR. how will I do that?

Comment: `var d = new Date("Thu 1/1/2022 8:37 AM"); var s = "";s += d.getFullYear();
s += "-";var month = (d.getMonth() + 1);s += ((month < 10) ? "0": "") + month.toString();s += "-";var date = d.getDate();s += ((date < 10) ? "0": "") + date.toString();s += "T";var hour = d.getHours();s += ((hour < 10) ? "0": "") + hour.toString();s += ":";var minute = d.getMinutes();s += ((minute < 10) ? "0": "") + minute.toString();s += ":";var sec = d.getSeconds();s += ((sec< 10) ? "0": "") + sec.toString();s += "Z";document.write(s);`

Comment: [MDN suggests using a library to parse a date string and not js itself.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) A lot of people have used [moment.js in the past, but its at end-of-life.](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) They suggest you use something like Luxon, or Day.js.

Comment: What do you do when the copied date format changes? If outlook is updated, or they change their email client, or copy from a different app?

Comment: @ourmandave - Outlook app must rely on either what format is set in its options, or the system on which it runs. So let you just rely on the power of JS's datetime parsing function. Date formats are standardized so Outlook's datetime must always  be parsable.

Comment: User typed date (parsable in JS): `Thu 1/27/2022 8:37 AM` | 
JS rebuilt date before sending: `2022-01-27T08:37:00Z` | 
Server-side parsed date: `2022-01-27T08:37:00Z` (DateTime compatible). You have to deal with UTC DateTime and timezones too but that's another story.

Comment: @RivoR. noted on your suggestion I got `2022-01-27T08:37:00Z` how will I display it back to textbox when called for update/edi? Thank you

Comment: If you read about ISO-8601 datetime, the format of this date is like `YYYY-MM-DDT HH:mm:ssZ` so you know where each part (year, month, hour, etc.) is. So either you create a new `Date()` in JS directly from this value or you parse it to get each part and rebuild a new date and provide a few parameters (year, month, etc.). Once done, you display it in the textbox via `$("#txtDateTime").val(d.toString());` where `d` is the variable that contains the JS date.

Comment: Using your browser's console or a tool like JSFiddle online will be helpful to test the client-side parsing and the rebuilding date part.

Comment: @RivoR. Can you post your whole answer so that I can tag it as correct if it's works. Thank you so much btw.

Comment: @RivoR. I'm just wondering how will I come up with Thu 1/27/2022 8:37 AM from 2022-01-27T08:37:00Z specially the `Thu` part

Comment: Well, once you create the date in JS, you can use ‘getDay()’ on the date. It gives you the ordinal number of the day of the week part of that date. Now you should be able to rebuild the datetime as a string in outlook format.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(data.DateTime);
```

It should figure out, and accept the day of week part you have.